# How can I convert .ort models to other formats such as .onnx?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow.js, onnxruntime, tfjs-node

How do I convert .ort models to .onnx or any other models. I asked in a discord server few seconds later a guy dmed me and said "I can help you but I will charge 100$" idk why does it even cost that much.

I have searched on internet, spent a whole day but I couldn't find it, we can convert .onnx to .ort but not .ort to .onnx file format? Maybe because it's compressed? (This is my first question on stackoverflow)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.